# Rspec: "No route matches" on scoped api route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've got problem with RSpec and scoped route. Route looks like this

```
      namespace :api do
    scope module: :v1, constrains: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      resources :users, except:[:new]
    end 
end
```

and spec (spec/controllers/api/v1/users_controller_spec.rb) looks like this:

```
RSpec.describe Api::V1::UsersController, type: :controller do
  let(:current_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  before do
    allow(controller).to receive(:authenticate_request!).and_return(true)
  end

  describe 'GET #show' do
    it 'should show user details' do
      get api_user_path(current_user.id.to_s), nil, { 'Accept' => 'application/app.com; version=1' }
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"/api/users/57c6a615fd32bd11444f792f", :controller=>"api/v1/users"}
```

I've tried "api_user_url", :show and others but I think that the problem lays in that scope. My routes looks like this:

```
               api_users GET      /api/users(.:format)               api/v1/users#index {:constrains=>#<ApiConstraints:0x007fe6824dce50 @version=1, @default=true>}
                     POST     /api/users(.:format)               api/v1/users#create {:constrains=>#<ApiConstraints:0x007fe6824dce50 @version=1, @default=true>}
       edit_api_user GET      /api/users/:id/edit(.:format)      api/v1/users#edit {:constrains=>#<ApiConstraints:0x007fe6824dce50 @version=1, @default=true>}
            api_user GET      /api/users/:id(.:format)           api/v1/users#show {:constrains=>#<ApiConstraints:0x007fe6824dce50 @version=1, @default=true>}
                     PATCH    /api/users/:id(.:format)           api/v1/users#update {:constrains=>#<ApiConstraints:0x007fe6824dce50 @version=1, @default=true>}
                     PUT      /api/users/:id(.:format)           api/v1/users#update {:constrains=>#<ApiConstraints:0x007fe6824dce50 @version=1, @default=true>}
                     DELETE   /api/users/:id(.:format)           api/v1/users#destroy {:constrains=>#<ApiConstraints:0x007fe6824dce50 @version=1, @default=true>}
```

Comment: what about `get api_user_path(current_user)`?

Comment: Nope, it's in that "and others" part. In fact it was my first approach. Sorry for being so vague!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in a typo 'constrains' in routes file:

```
scope module: :v1, constrains: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
```

Should be 'constraints', only `t` missing.